# 45 degree quine

Tags: ascii-art, code-challenge, quine

A very simple golf this time, but should be fun to do.

## Challenge

Output your code, but rotated 45 (or -45) degrees. E.g:

`lorem ipsum dolor sit amet`

becomes

```
                         t
                        e
                       m
                      a

                    t
                   i
                  s

                r
               o
              l
             o
            d

          m
         u
        s
       p
      i

    m
   e
  r
 o
l
```

This logic follows for newlines, too:

`lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
consectetur adipiscing`

becomes

```
                         t
                        e
                       m
                      a
                       g
                    t n
                   i i
                  s c
                   s
                r i
               o p
              l i
             o d
            d a

          m r
         u u
        s t
       p e
      i t
       c
    m e
   e s
  r n
 o o
l c
```

Of course, the difficulty is that you have to output your own code in this format.

## Scoring

Find position *b* (the amount of bytes in your code). on the X-axis of the formula \$y=\left(\frac{b}{8}-15\right)^2-n\$ (given *n* is the number of newlines). The lower the score, the better. Newlines are encouraged, as they made rendering it harder. Also, -15 bonus points for doing -45 degrees, as opposed to 45. My examples were -45 degrees.

## Rules

- Standard loopholes apply.
- No reading your own source.
- There must be a space between one line of code and the next, if you choose to do so
- Every line must be at least 5 characters long.
- Newlines cannot be replaced with '\n'. Tabs should be replaced with two spaces.
- Every line must do something; when removed, the program must not work
- No trailing newlines (unless for an implicit return) or no-ops.
- Blank newlines should be rendered with a space in its place (you can assume its a line of contents ' ')

Comment: What does "There must be a space between one line of code and the next, if you choose to do so" mean?

Comment: If you take a look at my second example, the text that was originally on two lines is now on one line, separated by space. E.g you can see it goes 'L C' on the bottom row of the second example, not 'LC'

Comment: Also, the scoring system seems to mean that there's no point to having code under 120 bytes?

Comment: I am sad that the second line is two columns right instead of one right and one down.

Comment: May we print anything to STDERR?

Comment: How does the scoring work? I feel like I did it wrong, I hv=ave the smallest byte count, but the highest score? My program fits all of the rules too! I feel like I'm missing something here...

Comment: Just FYI, this isn't code-golf anymore, it's code-challenge, since the criterion isn't strictly lowest byte count.

Comment: I think what @dfeuer meant was whether the space between characters was optional or not, since you specify the conflicting statements `There must be a space` and `if you choose to do so`

Comment: @JoKing If you choose to have newlines in your code

Comment: How do trailing newlines get rotated?  Do I need to add any characters for them?

Comment: @SriotchilismO'Zaic There can't be trailing newlines, since each line must have at least 5 chars

Comment: What do you mean by `Every line must do something; when removed, the program must not work`? For example, my Perl 6 solution still *runs* when one of my padded lines is removed but it doesn't produce the correct output anymore. Similarly, most one-line solutions will still *run* when the newlines are removed, and they *do* produce the correct output (nothing). Do you mean to invalidate my solution or the other solutions?

Comment: Are we allowed trailing spaces? Can we see an example of quines rotated 45 degrees, rather than -45. Especially multi-line please

Answer (score 2):

## [Gol><>](https://github.com/Sp3000/Golfish), 120 bytes, score 0

```
sP#|oao|o `FLFl                                                                                                        "
```

Adding a ton of no-ops makes my score really low, so I'm just going to go with it even though it hurts my heart to see so many no-ops doing absolutely nothing :(

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PScsszvj/vzhAuSY/Mb8mXyHBzcctR4FOQOn/fwA)

**golfed answer**, 16 bytes, Score : 152?!

```
sP#|oao|o `FLFl"
```

Wow, that is much smaller and more correct than my previous answer!!! (my other ones were backwards!)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PScsszvj/vzhAuSY/Mb8mXyHBzcctR@n/fwA)

Comment: try adding no-ops till your byte count is 120, you'll have a score of 0

Comment: You can get a negative score if you combined no-ops with new lines

Comment: @EmbodimentofIgnorance So basically if I am patient enough, and have enough time to waste, I can get an ridiculously low score?!

Comment: That is exactly what I'm saying, and why the current scoring system is broken.

Comment: @EmbodimentofIgnorance I feel like the scoring should just be based off of bytes, and perhaps penalties for trailing newlines, rather than this weird equation

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), Score 50.765625

```cs
var s="var s={0}{1}{0};for(int i=0;;)WriteLine(new String(' ',i)+string.Format(s,(char)34,s)[i++]);";for(int i=0;;)WriteLine(new String(' ',i)+string.Format(s,(char)34,s)[i++]);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTS7O/P@/LLFIodhWCUJVG9RWG9YCSeu0/CKNzLwShUxbA2trzfCizJJUn8y8VI281HKF4JKizLx0DXUFdZ1MTe1iME/PLb8oN7FEo1hHIzkjsUjT2ESnWDM6U1s7VtNaiaqm/f8PAA)

Also prints to STDERR, if this is invalid I will change it.

Answer (score 1):

## Japt `-S`, 25 bytes, Score: 116

```
25Çî iRiZgQi"25Çî iRiZgQi
```

[Run it online](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=MjXH7iBpUmlaZ1FpIjI1x+4gaVJpWmdRaQ==&input=LVM=)

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), Score -14

```perl6
<+map
{say(
~($_,)
.indent(
$++))
},[Z]
"<$_>[]~~
.EVAL#1234567"
.words
.map:{
.fmt(
"%-14s"
).comb
}>[]~~
.EVAL#1234567
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7/99GOzexgKu6OLFSg6tOQyVeR5NLLzMvJTWvRINLRVtbU5OrVic6KpZLyUYl3i46tq6OS881zNFH2dDI2MTUzFyJS688vyilmEsPaIxVNZdeWi5Qo5KqrqFJsRKXpl5yfm4SVy0Wjf//AwA)

New solution since my old one (below) might (?) be invalidated by the new rules. The output looks like:

```perl6
< { ~ . $ } " . . . . " ) } .
 + s ( i + , < E w m f % . > E
  m a $ n + [ $ V o a m - c [ V
   a y _ d ) Z _ A r p t 1 o ] A
    p ( , e ) ] > L d : ( 4 m ~ L
         ) n     [ # s {   s b ~ #
            t     ] 1       "     1
             (     ~ 2             2
                    ~ 3             3
                       4             4
                        5             5
                         6             6
                          7             7
                           "
```

I'm not sure if this is valid output since there's no example of a normal 45 degree quine in the question itself (this one is mirrored as well as rotated).

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), Score: -8

```perl6
<+map {say .indent($++),' 'x($++ <5)*16},"<$_>~~.EVAL".comb#123>>~~.EVAL
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7/99GOzexQKG6OLFSQS8zLyU1r0RDRVtbU0ddQb0CxFKwMdXUMjSr1VGyUYm3q6vTcw1z9FHSS87PTVI2NDK2gwlxKYAA8eT//wA)

Pads the code by 8 lines of 5 space characters, and then adds trailing spaces to the first 5 lines.

Comment: Doesn't this break the rule `Every line must be at least 5 characters long`?

Comment: @Emigna Ah, missed that. Fixed

Comment: Nice! If this program is -14 bytes, I can just download it over and over again! Free storage!

Comment: @Redwolf This isn't [tag:code-golf], the score is from a (rather bad) formula which goes negative with enough newlines

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 40 bytes, score 100

```
≔´α´↗´´´≔´Ｆ´α´↗´⁺´´´´´ι´↗´αα↗´≔Ｆα↗⁺´´ι↗α
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5//9R55RDW85tPLTlUdv0Q1tAECzyfs8yJOFHjbsgciB4bidU9NzGcxsh0p1TgOrBHKjKczuB7HMb////r5sIAA)

Based off the [standard Charcoal quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/121529/39244)

Comment: 37 bytes: `≔´α´↶´¹´´´≔´Ｆ´α´⁺´´´´´ι´αα↶¹´≔Ｆα⁺´´ια`

Comment: @Neil Technically, you're just making the score worse :o

Comment: The reason for this is that making really short quines isn't really much of a challenge any more, so instead the longer it is the higher the score (for a little while)

Comment: @GezaKerecsenyi Yeah that's not going to work... basically every single quine under our definition is payload-capable so they can be lengthened arbitrarily

Comment: Couldn't you add no-ops to make your score smaller (like spaces)?